# How to make a TextView show a value from a AsynTask class

Tags: android, json

I have an AsynTask which retrieve data from a web service and with this data to be viewed on the UI. So, in my MainActivity, I have a textView.

This is the data I received from the webservice:

```
{"name":"ezio","country":"italy"}{"name":"fufu","country":"tutu"}{"name":"chikaka","country":"aceVentura"}
```

The problem is, I do not know how to set the textView with the value of 'result' from the ClientConnection class. When I run the application, the textView is empty.

public class ClientConnection extends AsyncTask {

```
public static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.15/test.php";

static JSONObject jObj = null;
public static String result = "";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    // public JSONObject connect(){
    try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.e("HTTPStatus error:","Status not okay");
        }

        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            str.append(line + "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        result = str.toString();

        JSONObject jsonObject = convertToJson(result);

        // jsonObject.get()
        //result = jsonObject.getString("name");
        //JSONArray google = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(null, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Log.e("Error","don't know what exception though");
    }

    return result;
}

private JSONObject convertToJson(String test){

    JSONArray clients = new JSONArray();

    try{
        jObj = new JSONObject(test);

    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}

public String getResult(){
        return result;
    }
    public JSONObject getjObj(){
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

And this is the Main Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Button buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);

        final ClientJSONParsingActivity clientJSONParsingActivity = new ClientJSONParsingActivity();

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new ClientConnection().execute();

                textView.setText(new ClientConnection().getResult());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update textview in your asynctask.  `onPostExecute()` method runs on UI thread

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
```

Comment: I have added this piece of code as all of you have suggested. Here it is, 

    

protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
            activity.setTextView(getResult());
    }


This works as now my textview shows      {"name":"ezio","country":"italy"}{"name":"fufu","country":"tutu"}{"name":"chikaka","country":"aceVentura"}

However, I'm not quite sure this is good coding as I am creating a new reference to the main activity. Isn't there a way specifically made for Android to perform those tasks?

Comment: Why don't you return parsed JSON Object as String if you need only one value from JSON Object - not the whole  StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

You can display the result in the onPostExecute in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the text view as an argument to the asynctask and set it in onPostExecute. On my mobile so no code, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

add this code under your doinbackground;

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
(find your text view here from the context where textview it is)
          textView.setText(result);
      }
```